# Why am I not able to populate my Array object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dojo

```
if (typeof response == "object") {
    store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data : response
    });
    console.warn("Loaded to Store");
    var itemArray = new Array();
    var completed = function(items) {
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            console.log(store.getValue(items[i],"itemlabel"));
            itemArray.push(store.getValue(items[i]));
        }
    };
    var error = function() {
        console.log("Error in fetching data from Store");
    };

    store.fetch({onComplete: completed, onError: error});
    console.warn("Item count"+ itemArray.length);
```

So my Item Count gives Always 0 but

```
console.log(store.getValue(items[i],"itemlabel"));
```

In the callback method the above get print the value.

So if i want to populate my `itemArray` what can i do?

Comment: As a side note, you should never use `new Array()`, instead just use the `[]` notation: `var itemArray = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing `itemArray.length` before the array gets populated with any data in the `completed` function, because `completed` will be called asynchronously.

If you want to print the actual length of `itemArray`, you should do it after the for-loop in `completed`.

Comment: I augmented my answer. Please provide more context for what you're trying to do if my answer isn't satisfactory.

Comment: I want that array to be populated so that i can use it later.

Comment: The array *is* getting populated, when the `completed` callback is executed. You have to wait for the asynchronous callback to complete.

Comment: So to make it wait util the callback is over,what can i do?

Comment: I'm no Dojo expert, but maybe there's something in the documentation about calling `fetch` synchronously. Another alternative would be to call the function that uses `itemArray` from the `completed` function.

Answer (score 1):

Hello the answer to your problem is quite easy, but first i'd recommand using

```
var completed = function(items) {
    dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
        console.log(store.getValue(items[i],"itemlabel"));
        itemArray.push(store.getValue(items[i]));
    }, this);
    proceedToNextStep(itemArray);
};
```

and then you create a function that will be used to keep on the process once the itemArray is loaded..

```
proceedToNextStep: function(itemArray){
    // whatever you need to do
},
```

You could also use dojo.publish / dojo.subscribe